# How to sort a list in python in non-decreasing order?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have the following list

```
distances = ['5.67', '8.91', '6.48', '9.32', '13.38', '14.99']
```

I have did some research and have tried

```
sorted(distances , key = float)
```

and I have also tried

```
distances.sort()
```

However neither have worked. Wondering what i am doing wrong?

Comment: How do you want them sorted?

Comment: sorted returns a new sorted list, if you want to sort in-place just do `distances.sort(key=float)`

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with `sorted(distances , key = float)`.

Comment: Rather than non-decreasing order isn't it easier to just say increasing order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach should work. How do you want the values sorted?

```
distances = ['5.67', '8.91', '6.48', '9.32', '13.38', '14.99']

distances = sorted(distances, key=float)

print(distances)

['5.67', '6.48', '8.91', '9.32', '13.38', '14.99']
```

Comment: If you are just going to assign back to the same name, use `sort` to sort in-place instead of allocating a new `list` object. (Unless, of course, some *other* name refers to the original list as well and you want to keep that reference.)